# Disadvantage of circular EJB dependencies?

Tags: java, jboss, dependencies, ejb

Let's assume we have two EJBs `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`. `ServiceA` provides a public method that is required in `ServiceB`. At the same time, `ServiceB` is present in `ServiceA`.

**Is there any problem having this circular dependency?**

```
@Stateless
public class ServiceA implements IServiceA {

  @EJB(mappedName = IServiceB.JNDI_NAME_LOCAL)
  private IServiceB serviceB;

  // ...

  public void foo() {
    // ...
  }
}

@Stateless
public class ServiceB implements IServiceB {

  @EJB(mappedName = IServiceA.JNDI_NAME_LOCAL)
  private IServiceA serviceA;

  // ...

  private void bar() {
    serviceA.foo();
  }
}
```

I always tried to avoid such an architecture, but a co-worker recently introduced this mutual usage. I feel it is wrong to use a service in a service that, on its part, uses the first service which uses the second service again... You get it. Technically, this obviously works, but I'm not entirely happy with it and would rather introduce a `ServiceC` for the `foo()` method.

So I wonder:

1. Is it okay to have this circular dependency?
2. If not, are there technical reasons for not doing this?
3. If it is possible technically, are there any arguments against it design-wise?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is beyond EJB, it is about coupling between classes.

> Is it okay to have this circular dependency?

No because to prevent undesirable rising maintainability cost, two classes should avoid having strong coupling between them if it is not required.

Here you have a strong coupling as A knows B and B knows A.

> If not, are there technical reasons for not doing this?

Resolution of  circular dependencies may be complicated with some DI containers but in fact the most serious problem is not here.

With two-way dependencies (A sees B and B sees A), whatever I change A or B : methods (returned type and parameters) class hierarchy, etc.., the other class is potentially impacted.

For example in your code, B use the `foo()` method of A.
Suppose A uses the `bar()` method of B.

If I change the `foo()` method of A by adding a new parameter,  both A and B are modified and if I change the `bar()` method of B by adding a new parameter, again both A and B are modified. 
**This clearly shows a problem of responsibility definition between the classes. It encourages mix of responsibilities in the future changes, it decreases the  code readability and the consistency of the design and so it favors side-effects and regressions as any one of these classes is modified.**

While with a one-way dependency (A sees B but B doesn't see A), if I change A , B is not impacted as B doesn't know A.
So favor the one-way dependency.

> Technically, this obviously works, but I'm not entirely happy with it and would rather introduce a ServiceC for the foo() method.

We have not many details about the performed logic but your idea to introduce a intermediary class to avoid the two-way dependency seems rather good as it prevents a strong coupling

Another way of handling the problem would be, if it makes sense to change the responsibility of classes by moving the foo() method in the ServiceB class. In this way serviceB would not need any longer to depend on serviceA if it used it only to call the foo() method.

Answer (score 0):

Besides that this is not a good design. The main point is that circular dependencies in ejb field could lead to quite some problem if you are not using a Sinlgeton bean. Infact a quote from the spec says:

> The container must ensure that only one thread can be executing a
>   stateless or stateful session bean instance at any time. **Therefore,
>   stateful and stateless session beans do not have to be coded as
>   reentrant**. One implication of this rule is that an application cannot
>   make loopback calls to a stateless or stateful session bean instance.

If you have used this a lot of time and you didn't notice any problem or deadlock is because the Application Server has managed/solved this for you. Weblogic for example has this features. So I suggest to check first with the application server you are using. Quite the same applies to Message Driven Bean.

If instead you are using singleton, there are no problems at all. Again a quote from the spec:

> Special locking semantics apply to loopback calls on Singletons with
>   container-managed concurrency.
>
> If a loopback call occurs on a Singleton that already holds a Write lock on the same thread :
>
> - If the target of the loopback call is a Read method, the Read lock must
>     always be granted immediately, without releasing the original Write
>     lock.
> - If the target of the loopback call is a Write method, the call
>     must proceed immediately, without releasing the original Write lock.
>
> If a loopback call occurs on a Singleton that holds a Read lock on the
>   same thread ( but does not also hold a Write lock on the same thread ):
>
> - If the target of the loopback call is a Read method, the call must
>     proceed immediately, without releasing the original Read lock.
> - If the target of the loopback call is a Write method, a
>     javax.ejb.IllegalLoopbackException must be thrown to the caller.

As a final note, I am seeing you are using `mappedName`, but this is not supported by all the application servers, and each one may provide a different named. You should rather use `lookup`.